# Событие onclick JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Говорю сразу - JS изучаю совсем недавно, ошибка может быть очень глупой
Не работает событие onclick
Фрагмент кода HTML:

```
<table class="menu2">
    <form>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="every">Все</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2"><div id="math" onclick="ClickMath()">Математика</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="info">Информатика</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="fiz">Физика</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="gum">Гуманитарные науки</td>
    </form>
    </table>
</nav>
<div class="lenta">
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/math.jpg" class="math"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/math5.jpg" class="math"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/fiz1.jpg" class="fiz"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/gum1.jpg" class="gum"></div>
</div>
```

Фрагмент CSS:

```
.fiz {
    width: 500px;
}

.math {
    width: 500px;
}

.info {
    width: 500px;
}

.gum {
    width: 500px;
}
```

Функция JS:

```
function ClickMath()

    {
        alert("Вы нажали Математика");
        var m=document.getElementsByClassName("math");
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<m.length; i++)
        {
            m.style.display='block';
            m.style.color='#e86d81';
        }
        var f=document.getElementsByClassName("fiz");
        for (i=0; i<f.length; i++)
        {
            f.style.display='none';
        }
        var info=document.getElementsByClassName("info");
        for (i=0; i<info.length; i++)
        {
            info.style.display='none';
        }
        var g=document.getElementsByClassName("gum");
        for (i=0; i<g.length; i++)
        {
            g.style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вместо редактирования вопроса, изменяя ошибочный текст на верный, лучше добавь свой ответ, в котором поясни что именно поменялось, чтобы заработало.

Comment: Ольга, После исправления ошибки вами же ваш код заработал. Вы просто сами этого не заметили. Просто нажмите на слово «Математика» но только в исправленной версии.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так , у вас синтаксическая ошибка ... int в js нет .

```js
function ClickMath()

    {
        alert("Вы нажали Математика");
        var m=document.getElementsByClassName("math");
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<m.length; i++)
        {
            m.style.display='block';
            m.style.color='#e86d81';
        }
        var f=document.getElementsByClassName("fiz");
        for (i=0; i<f.length; i++)
        {
            f.style.display='none';
        }
        var info=document.getElementsByClassName("info");
        for (i=0; i<info.length; i++)
        {
            info.style.display='none';
        }
        var g=document.getElementsByClassName("gum");
        for (i=0; i<g.length; i++)
        {
            g.style.display='none';
        }
    }
```

```css
.fiz {
    width: 500px;
}

.math {
    width: 500px;
}

.info {
    width: 500px;
}

.gum {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<table class="menu2">
    <form>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="every">Все</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2"><div id="math" onclick="ClickMath()">Математика</div></td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="info">Информатика</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="fiz">Физика</td>
        <td align="center" class="tr2" id="gum">Гуманитарные науки</td>
    </form>
    </table>
</nav>
<div class="lenta">
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/math.jpg" class="math"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/math5.jpg" class="math"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/fiz1.jpg" class="fiz"></div>
    <div class="mem"><img src="intellect/gum1.jpg" class="gum"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ольга значит дальше ошибки есть уже. это же кусок кода.